# How does coloring C argument works in hexbin (Matplotlib, python)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am facing a probably stupid problem in matplotlib, using hexbin (https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hexbin.html) with weights (argument C=).

When I am filling the C argument, not only the ouput color changes but also the shape. Here is a very simple code snippet reproducing the behavior:

```
npts = int(2e5)

# Create a random distribution and another one as it perturbation
x1 = np.random.randint(0,3000,npts)
x2 = x1 + np.random.normal(loc=0,scale=75,size=npts)

# Same for the second axis variable
y1 = np.random.randint(280,310,npts)
y2 = y1 + np.random.normal(loc=0,scale=2,size=npts)

# Plot
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1)
ax = axes[0]
ax.hexbin(y2-y1,x1,mincnt=1,extent=[-8,8,0,3000], gridsize=150) 
#
ax = axes[1]
res = ax.hexbin(y2-y1,x1,C=x1,mincnt=1,extent=[-8,8,0,3000], gridsize=150)

fig.savefig(f"hexbin_weights.png")
plt.show()
```

And the corresponding output:
[image: Snippet output]

To my understanding, as the x and y coordinates of the points are identical, only the color on the two plots should change. However, it is clearly not the case.

Has anyone any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: You've set mincount to 1, and x1 has small values so the count in the sparse bins never gets to 1, so the bin does not get filled.

Comment: This happens to solve the problem ! I assumed that mincnt would always apply to the number of samples landing in the hexagon and not the to color mappable... ^^ Thanks :)